# GitHub Actions swift-tools-version 5.7.0

Tags: swift, continuous-integration, github-actions, xcodebuild, building-github-actions

I am interested in running build for my Swift project on CI with GitHub Actions

I use the following `ci.yml`:

```yaml
Build:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Install Swift
        uses: slashmo/install-swift@v0.2.1
        with:
          version: 5.7
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Build
        uses: sersoft-gmbh/xcodebuild-action@v2
        with:
          project: <Project>.xcodeproj
          scheme: <Scheme>
          destination: "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro Max"
          action: build
```

I am facing a problem here:

```bash
xcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
    package at '/Users/runner/work/path/to/my/package' is using Swift tools version 5.7.0 but the installed version is 5.5.0
```

I want to use `swift-tools-version` equal to `5.7.0`, not the lower one

Please, help me install the version I need

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but using the image `macOS-12` instead of the `macOS-latest`. You'll have the same error message but instead of having `5.5.0` as the installed version, it will say `5.6.0`. I've been checking and looks like we either need to wait until they propagate new runner images.

Comment: I got a similar error. I just pasted the error message into github copilot for vscode and it rewrote the .yml file and fixed the problem. No need to overthink anymore 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I made it work. I added this step in my workflow:

```
      - name: Select Xcode
        run: sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode_14.0.1.app"
```

and then specified the simulator environment:

```
        env:
          destination: 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro,OS=16.0'
```

Comment: That you for your solution!
May be you know how to handle the following error with this config:

`xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode_14.0.1.app'`

Comment: According to this thread  we are having the ability to use xcode-version 14.0 since next week
https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6225

Comment: True, I just saw that. Before, in that same thread, they were saying that the new image was already applied and we only needed to wait for changes propagation, now they say there were some issues. Looks like everything makes sense for now. As per your question, did you add it with double or single quotes?

Comment: I just copied your variant. So, double quotes)
Did you managed that working? Please, help me)

Comment: Did you try changing the runner image you're using from `runs-on: macOS-latest` to `runs-on: macOS-12` ?

Comment: That is magic! Idk why `macOS-latest` does not support Xcode-14, while `macOS-12` does!
Anyway, that is better to wait the updated macOS image on the 3rd of October 2022

Answer (score 0):

Currently macos-14 is available on Github machines. So below action is valid and working for me;

```yaml
# This workflow will build a Swift project
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-swift

name: Swift

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-14

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: List Xcode installations
      run: sudo ls -1 /Applications | grep "Xcode"

    - name: Select Xcode 15.2
      run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_15.2.app/Contents/Developer
    
    - name: Build
      run: swift build -v
    
    - name: Run tests
      run: swift test -v
```